# Using Firebase Storage and Database together

Tags: database-design, firebase-realtime-database, telescope, nosql

I'm building a new site using Firebase. The backend will store user profiles, files (PDFs and anything else) that will each have a title and a number of tags.

I'm planning on using Telescope (NOVA) to create a reddit style page listing to let users upvote/downvote posts.

How should one structure the Firebase Database AND Storage? Obviously I store the files in Storage - but how about everything else? I want to build a robust structure for the database that will scale easily.

Comment: There is no way to answer that question without knowing a lot more about your application (which makes it too broad to answer on StackOverflow). I recommend you read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and then study the [Firebase documentation on data modeling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use both Firebase and Nova together, since Nova works with Meteor and MongoDB?

Comment: Oh yeah I was trying to figure that part out - I think you're right. Do you guys happens to know any other react frameworks with upvote/downvote functionality.